# Express: Page is not updating on res.redirect(). I have to manually reload page to see changes. How to fix this?

Tags: node.js, express

basically, I have a variable cart in my user schema. I am updating it using the following code.

```
app.get("/cart/:id", function (req, res) {
    var productId = req.params.id;
    Post.findById(productId, function (err, product) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            let index = req.user.cart.indexOf(productId);
            if (index >= 0) {
                req.user.cart.splice(index, 1);
            }
            req.user.save();
            console.log(req.user.cart);
            res.redirect("/cart");
        }
    });
});
```

After updating I am redirecting back to /cart page to display the updated page.

```
app.get("/cart", async (req, res) => {
    let cart = req.user.cart;
    console.log(cart);

    let products = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        let product = await Post.findById(cart[i]);
        products.push(product);
    }
    res.render("cart.ejs", {
        products: products
    });
});
```

The problem is my /cart page is showing the old details. It shows the updated data only if I reload the page manually. How can I fix it so that the /cart page always shows the updated data.

Comment: You maybe need to await `req.user.save();` (make sure you do this in an async function)

Comment: Thank you. I used the callback function in save() to redirect. It's working now.